# How to terminate context after using zeromq in c#

Tags: c#, zeromq

can not go out using (var context = new Context(1)) {} , how to terminate it

python has context.term(),  but c# do not have it !

```
using (var context = new Context(1))
            {
                //using (Socket server = context.Socket(SocketType.REQ))
                using (Socket server = context.Socket(SocketType.PUB))
                {
                    var serializer = new VpfsLiveFeed.MessageTypes.JsonSerializer();
                    var jsonMessage = new VpfsLiveFeed.MessageTypes.LivefeedEnvelope
                    {
                        Message = new VpfsLiveFeed.MessageTypes.LivefeedMessage
                        {
                            MessageType = "TERMINATION_REQUEST",
                            MessageId = "Testing Message",
                            ReplyEmailAddress = "VPLAB@localhost.com"
                        }
                    };
                    server.Connect(string.Format("tcp://{0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["termination_host"]));
                    server.Send(serializer.MessageToBytes<VpfsLiveFeed.MessageTypes.LivefeedEnvelope>(jsonMessage), Encoding.UTF8);
                    server.Dispose();
                }
                context.Dispose(); // stop here is not go out of this {}
            }
StopAllThread = true;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
            if (myHost != null)
                myHost.Close();
```

it do not go to StopAllThread = true;

Comment: im not getting you. you mean you are not going out of that `using (var context = new Context(1))` block? if that's the case, did you see any exceptions that was thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this...

```
context.Terminate()
```

Comment: do not have this function to choose in c# in vs2012

Comment: You're using clrzmq? `ZmqContext.Terminate()` is a method, but what version are you using?

Comment: @raffian can i Terminate the context when there are still sockets left?
are the sockets correctly closed when i terminate the context?

Comment: @leozilla It's better to close the sockets first, then terminate; see source: https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/blob/master/src/ZeroMQ/ZmqContext.cs

Comment: @raffian: ok, but i need to close/diapose the sockets in the thread they were creates in, right? thats adds some additional complexity.

Comment: @leozilla The sockets should be in their own threads, ready to catch an interrupt when `terminate` is invoked; at that point, close the socket and use linger when the socket was created to allow time for it to close safely.

Comment: @raffian all my sockets have their own thread. so the workflow would be create sockets in their own thread, wait until all threads that contain a socket are finished and therefor sockets are disposed (becuase they are wrapped in a using block) and when all sockets are disposes then dispose the context, is that correct? And when creating a socket use linger?

Comment: @leozilla yes, set linger when creating the socket; the rest sounds good, go and try it out!